# Entity Framework include many from nested child

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Lets say I have Entities as such

```
Person
------
List<Person> Children
List<Item> FaveBooks
List<Item> FaveSweets
```

If I want to eager load children for a personId this is fine.

```
dataContext.People.Where(x => x.id == personId)
      .Include(x.Children).First()
```

If I also want to include Childrens FaveBooks, simple

```
dataContext.People.Where(x => x.id == personId)
      .Include(x.Children.Select(c => c.FaveBooks)).First()
```

How would one also include FaveSweets from the Children?

```
dataContext.People.Where(x => x.id == personId)
      .Include(x.Children.Select(c => new { c.FaveBooks, c.FaveSweets })).First()
```

The above does not work as I get `The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type.`

Comment: Use multiple calls: `.Include(x => x.Children.Select(c => c.FaveBooks)).Include(x => x.Children.Select(c => c.FaveSweets))`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
   dataContext.People.Where(x => x.id == personId).Include(x => x.Children.Select(c => c.FaveBooks)).Include(x => x.Children.Select(c => c.FaveSweets)).First();
```

Comment: My real structure is quite a lot deeper but if this is the only way then so be it :)

Comment: After trying this it does not seem to actually work for me, it is timing out but with either one of my includes alone it is fine. I'll have to do some digging.